# Error in getting the root path of project

Tags: file

I downloaded my new project using FTP from my local. But when I check the codes if it is working in my local. All the directories are not pointing to my Project root path.

In my downloaded file I have this path in the config.php

```
/okushon/home/pages/js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js
```

When I checked in the browser it doesn't go to the file

But when I change the path to:

```
./okushon/home/pages/js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js
```

It goes to the file.

I don't know why in the live server it works but in my local the path doesn't work.

Comment: How is any of this related to php? You are requesting a javascript file in your HTML document.

Comment: My example only is the js file but the other files like images doesn't worked also.

Comment: And how are images related to php?

Comment: Ok I got it sorry. I already changed the title.

Answer (score 0):

To include javascript files with an absolute path you should use something like

`http://www.your-domain.de/js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js`

To use it on your local web server, replace it by something like

`http://localhost/your-project/js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js`

The best way is to use a path variable in an extra file which is included in every page:

```
if((isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) && 'blablabla'==$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])){
    $incPath = '/path/to/your/files/';
    $httpPath = 'http://www.your-domain.de/';
}
else {
    $incPath = '/local/path/to/your/files/';
    $httpPath = 'http://localhost/your-project/';
}
```

Comment: I already have that kind of process...